# Database field properties

Tags: vba, ms-access

Follow Vba routine:

```
Dim CampoRS As string
Dim Requerido As Boolean
Dim Zero As Bollean
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

With frmCurriculum
       
    Set rs = dbCRM.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCurriculum", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges, dbPessimistic)
    rs.MoveFirst
    For n = 0 To .Controls.Count - 1
    
        CampoRS = .Controls.item(n).Tag
        
            Requerido = rs.Fields(CampoRS).Required
            Zero = rs.Fields(CampoRS).AllowZeroLenght

  ...
```

Using DAO, this routine get the properties "Required" and "AllowZeroLenght" of a field in a recordset.

I need get the same properties but using ADO

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Microsoft+Products/access/Chapter+6.+Data/Recipe+6.6+Get+a+Complete+List+of+Field+Properties+from+a+Table+or+Query/   Please try Googling your question before posting...

Comment: Thanks. But i'm using ADO access. In DAO dont have any poblem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/the-field-object?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks Tim. But in the article not content any reference to then 'Required' and 'AllowZeroLength" properties

Comment: If you look here https://flylib.com/books/en/3.9.1.29/1/ you can see that the `Field.Attributes` property is a bitmask, so you can check for example `? (rs.Fields("Name").Attributes and 64) = 64` (or use the `adFldMayBeNull` ADO constant) to check if a field is nullable, but I don't see the equivalent for "allow zero length" there.

Comment: This might be a case where you need to DAO/ADOX if you want both of those properties.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Your comment is an important aproach to resolve my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here https://flylib.com/books/en/3.9.1.29/1/ you can see that the `Field.Attributes` property is a bitmask, so you can check for example

```
 (rs.Fields("Name").Attributes and 64) = 64
```

(or use the `adFldMayBeNull` ADO constant) to check if a field is nullable, but I don't see the equivalent for "allow zero length" there.

This might be a case where you need to DAO/ADOX if you want both of those properties though.